# Difference between lying, misleading, and deceiving

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

What is the difference between lying, misleading, and deceiving? I know they're really similar but there must be a difference between them.

Comment: Before we get into that, better change the title. There is no noun *_misled_ derived from the verb _mislead_. _Lie_ has a zero-derived noun _lie_, and _deceive_ nominalizes to _deception_; but you can't nominalize _mislead_ to just one word.

Comment: @JohnLawler fixed

Comment: Good question, which actually occurred to me 2 days ago, but you asked it before I could! You can put all 3 words to a standard online/offline dictionary and compare the meaning -- if you are satisfied, you can quote the definitions here and answer your own question, which is actually encouraged by StackExchange!

Comment: I mislead, you deceive, he lies.

Answer (score 1):

Lying is the act of telling something known to be false. Deceiving is using some sort of plot for personal advantage. Misleading is causing someone to have a wrong idea or impression of something.
They are all pretty similar, but the devil's in the details here. Lying and misleading might be tools used for the purposes of deception, but saying that someone was deceived is ultimately saying that there was a trick or scheme involved for the deceiver's gain. Misleading doesn't necessarily involve telling falsehoods or untruths, just that the end result is in causing someone to have a misconception about something. Lying, meanwhile, is the act of saying something that is demonstrably not true while knowing it to be not true.

Definitions referenced:
https://www.google.com/search?q=define:subterfuge
https://www.google.com/search?q=define:deceive
https://www.google.com/search?q=define:lie
https://www.google.com/search?q=define:mislead
(Google doesn't seem to cite which dictionary they're sourcing as being the top result, but the definitions given are accurate enough and consistent with the definitions given in the other online dictionaries.)

Comment: It’s better to quote and cite dictionary definitions than to make one up yourself- they’ve thought much harder about how to capture the meaning succinctly without unwanted side effects.

Comment: Good answer, though you could cite standard definitions, as suggested by Jim. You are right in saying that somebody can mislead or deceive even **without lying** if he/she   manages to employ half-truths or otherwise twists their interpretation of things to effectively deceive/mislead the target. You have also brought out the point that misleading can possibly be unintentional but deception is implicitly a deliberate action.

Comment: @Jim That depends on the dictionary. But very well expressed.

Comment: @Jim I was referencing the dictionary definitions in writing my answer, though I definitely should've mentioned that. I absolutely agree that the standard dictionary definitions have had much more thought put into wording them more succinctly than I have, but that succinctness is often more confusing than a slightly more plainly-worded, less succinct definition.

Comment: @Schir To quote the [popular meme](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/538/731/0fc.gif), "Why Don’t We Have Both?".